# Qt does not know accept for socket programming

Tags: qt, sockets

If I press a button, a network server should get started. But it seems the compiler does not know the right accept-function. This line:

`sockConnection = accept(hSocket, &remoteAddr, &iRemoteAddrLen);`

gets this error:

> no matching function for call to 'NetConf::accept(SOCKET&, sockaddr_in*, socklen_t*)'

It appears that the accept-function is part of a Qt Object and not the socket one I would like to use. I read about including "socket.h" but cant find it on my system (Windows 7 - 64 bit, Qt library 4.8.6). Any suggestions?

Comment: Please edit your question and format the code properly.

Answer (score 2):

Qt is a framework that abstracts away the requirement for calling low level functions such as accept.

If you want a TCP-based network server, start with a [QTcpServer](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/QTcpServer.html) class object and call its [listen](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtcpserver.html#listen) function

If you've connected a QObject's slot to the QTcpServer's [newConnection](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtcpserver.html#newConnection) signal, you'll be notified when a connection is made.

Once notified of a new connection, you then call [nextPendingConnection](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtcpserver.html#nextPendingConnection) which returns a QTcpSocket, which you can use to communicate with the client by using its available functions as described in the [Qt docs for this class](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtcpsocket.html).